# Why is *a++; not incrementing the value a points to?

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

Hellow
I am a beginner in coding who is learning pointer. this is a simple code of passing pointers
to functions but I am getting wrong input.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void increment(int *a){
    *a++;
}
int main(){
    int a=2;
    //int *p=&a;
    increment(&a);
    cout<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

output is showing 2;

Comment: Operator precedence rules strike again. `*a++;` is `*(a++);` but you want `(*a)++;`

Comment: By any chance, learn modern C++ and use references instead. Don't use raw pointers and pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

What happened here? The C++ grammar effectively defines something we commonly refer to as "operator precedence" (since it's defined by the grammar, you won't find chapter in the C++ standard where the precedence would be listed in a convenient way, but [there are websites](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) that worked it out).

In `*a++;`, the pointer will be increased (`a++`) and thus pointing to an invalid position. After that, the invalid pointer will be dereferenced (`*` operator), causing undefined behavior (UB). If you're learning, you want to get familiar with undefined behavior, because anything can happen.

To fix it, use parentheses to specify precedence explicity: `(*a)++;`.

Maybe you want to learn about references instead? Don't use raw pointers and pointer arithmetic. Compare your code to this code:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void increment(int& a){
    a++;
}
int main(){
    int a = 2;
    increment(a);
    cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```

Also: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)